# Instagram Ad Insights through FacebookBusiness SDK

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to grab the ad insights for my business' instagram ad campaigns. I have successfully pulled the facebook ad campaign statistics with this. Now I must know how the instagram ad campaigns are doing for each business. Does anyone have any insight on how to do this? I've been referencing the source code for days and I cannot seem to learn how to do this.

```
session = FacebookSession(
        app_id,
        app_secret,
        access_token,
    )
    api = FacebookAdsApi(session)
    FacebookAdsApi.set_default_api(api)
    campaign = AdCampaign(campaign_id)
    #grab a list of instagram ad campaigns
    # instagram_campaign = AdAccount(instagram_account_id)
    # instagram_campaign.get_insights(<fields,ect>)
    insights = []
    instagram_accounts = []
    i=0
    my_ads = []
    while(i<7):
        string_start_time = str(start_time)
        string_end_time = str(end_time)
        params = {
            'time_range': {
                'since': string_start_time,
                'until': string_end_time,
                },
            'fields': [
                #AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
                AdsInsights.Field.reach,
                AdsInsights.Field.unique_clicks,
                AdsInsights.Field.spend,
                AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
                AdsInsights.Field.cpm,
                AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
                AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
                #AdsInsights.Field.cost_per_unique_outbound_click
                #AdsInsights.Field.spend
                ],
            #'breakdowns': [
            #    AdsInsights.Breakdowns.age
            #]
                }
        insights.append(campaign.get_insights(params=params))
        #instagram_accounts.append(campaign.get_instagram_accounts(params=params))
        i+=1
        start_time += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        end_time += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```